# Twitter Bootstrap: Auto width for pill based menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm using twitter bootstrap for a website. Now I'm using the pills as a menu ( with java script ) But I want them to automatically fill the menu bar ( making them all the same size ).

I don't think it's build in with bootstrap so does anyone have a suggestion how to do this ?

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12 ban text-center">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills"  style="display: inline-block;">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="pill"><i class="icon-home"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Info" data-toggle="pill"><i class="icon-home ">Info </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Fotos" data-toggle="pill"><i class="icon-camera"></i> Foto's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact" data-toggle="pill"><i class="icon-home "> Contact </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

A drawing to make it clear:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmkqF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3 there's a new **btn-group-justified** class which might work for you

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Full details at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified

Comment: Anyway to do this without using BS3 ?

Comment: @CABenstein One option would be a full widt CSS table then manually size the % widths of the cells for each link

Comment: That worked, thanx for the help! I just removed the inline-block style and added a menu style that did the 25%